# Yet another central limit theorem question

Tags: probability, convergence, central-limit-theorem

> Let $\{X_n:n\ge1\}$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with 
>   $$P\{X_k=1\}=1-P\{X_k=0\}=\frac{1}{k}.$$
>   Set
>   $$S_n=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(X_k-\frac{1}{k}\right), \ B_n^2=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{k-1}{k^2}$$
>   Show that $\frac{S_n}{B_n}$ converges in distribution to the standard normal variable $Z$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

My attempt is to use the Lyapunov CLT, therefore we need to show there exists a $\delta>0$ such that,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{B_n^{2+\delta}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[|X_k-\frac{1}{k}|^{2+\delta}]=0. $$

So set $\delta=1$$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}E\left|X_k-k^{-1}\right|^{3}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{3}{k^2}+\frac{4}{k^3}-\frac{2}{k^4}\right)
$$
and
$$
B_n^3=\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2} \right) \sqrt{\left(  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2} \right)}
$$

By evaluating for large n's on the  computer it  shows how both $\sum_{k=1}^{n}E|X_k-k^{-1}|^{3} \to \infty$ and $B_n^3 \to \infty$  as $n \to \infty$.  But $B_n^3$ increases faster than $B_n^2$ so $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}E|X_k-k^{-1}|^{3}}{B_n^3} \to 0$. Can someone help me prove this convergence holds?

Comment: This is Example 27.3 of _Probability and Measure_ by Patrick Billingsley.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It may be instructive to demonstrate this result from first principles and basic results**, exploiting properties of cumulant generating functions (exactly as in standard proofs of the Central Limit Theorem).  It requires us to understand the rate of growth of [generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) $$H(n,s)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-s}$$ for $s=1, 2, \ldots.$  These growth rates are well-known and easily obtained by comparison to the integrals $\int_1^n x^{-s}dx$: they converge for $s \gt 1$ and otherwise diverge logarithmically for $s=1$.

---

Let $n \ge 2$ and $1 \le k \le n$.  By definition, the cumulant generating function (cgf) of $(X_k - 1/k)/B_n$ is

$$\psi_{k,n}(t) = \log\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(\frac{X_k - 1/k}{B_n}t\right)\right) = -\frac{t}{k B_n} + \log\left(1 + \frac{-1 + \exp(t/B_n)}{k}\right).$$

The series expansion of the right hand side, obtained from the expansion of $\log(1+z)$ around $z=0$, takes the form

$$\psi_{k,n}(t) = \frac{(k-1)}{2 k^2 B_n^2}t^2 + \frac{k^2 - 3k + 2}{6 k^3 B_n^3} t^3 + \cdots + \frac{k^{j-1} - \cdots \pm (j-1)!}{j! k^j B_n^j}t^j + \cdots.$$

The numerators of the fractions are polynomials in $k$ with leading term $k^{j-1}$.  Because the log expansion converges absolutely for $\left|\frac{-1 + \exp(t/B_n)}{k}\right| \lt 1$, this expansion converges absolutely when

$$\left|\exp(t/B_n) - 1\right| \lt k.$$

(In case $k=1$ it converges everywhere.) For fixed $k$ and increasing values of $n$, the (obvious) divergence of $B_n$ implies the domain of absolute convergence grows arbitrarily large.  Thus, **for any fixed $t$ and sufficiently large $n$, this expansion converges absolutely.**

For sufficiently large $n$, then, we may therefore sum the individual $\psi_{k,n}$ over $k$ term by term in powers of $t$ to obtain the cgf of $S_n/B_n$,

$$\psi_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n \psi_{k,n}(t) = \frac{1}{2}t^2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{B_n^j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \left(k^{-1} - \cdots \pm (j-1)!k^{-j}\right)\right)\frac{t^j}{j} + \cdots.$$

Taking the terms in the sums over $k$ one at a time requires us to evaluate expressions proportional to

$$b(s,j) = \frac{1}{B_n^j}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-s}$$

for $j \ge 3$ and $s=1, 2, \ldots, j$.  Using the asymptotics of generalized harmonic numbers mentioned in the introduction, it follows easily from

$$B_n^2 = H(n,1) - H(n,2) \sim \log(n)$$

that

$$b(1,j) \sim (\log(n))^{1-j/2}\to 0$$

and (for $s \gt 1$)

$$b(s,j) \sim (\log(n))^{-j/2}\to 0$$

as $n$ grows large.  Consequently all terms in the expansion of $\psi_n(t)$ beyond $t^2$ converge to zero, whence $\psi_n(t)$ converges to $t^2/2$ for any value of $t$.  Since convergence of the cgf implies convergence of the characteristic function, we conclude from the [Levy Continuity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy's_continuity_theorem) that $S_n/B_n$ approaches a random variable whose cgf is $t^2/2$: that is the standard Normal variable, *QED*.

---

**This analysis uncovers just how delicate the convergence is:** whereas in many versions of the Central Limit Theorem the coefficient of $t^j$ is $O(n^{1-j/2})$ (for $j \ge 3$), here the coefficient is only $O(((\log(n))^{1-j/2})$: the convergence is much slower.  In this sense the sequence of standardized variables "just barely" becomes Normal.

**We can see this slow convergence in a series of simulations.**  The histograms display $10^5$ independent iterations for four values of $n$.  The red curves are graphs of standard normal density functions for visual reference.  Although there is evidently a gradual tendency towards normality, even at $n=1000$ (where $(\log(n))^{-1/2} \approx 0.38$ is still sizable) there remains appreciable non-normality, as evidenced in the skewness (equal to $0.35$ in this sample).  (It is no surprise the skewness of this histogram is close to $(\log(n))^{-1/2}$, because that's precisely what the $t^3$ term in the cgf is.)

[image: Figure: histograms for n=30, 100, 300, 1000]

Here is the `R` code for those who would like to experiment further.

```R
set.seed(17)
par(mfrow=c(1,4))
n.iter <- 1e5
for(n in c(30, 100, 300, 1000)) {
  B.n <- sqrt(sum(rev((((1:n)-1) / (1:n)^2))))
  x <- matrix(rbinom(n*n.iter, 1, 1/(1:n)), nrow=n, byrow=FALSE)
  z <- colSums(x - 1/(1:n)) / B.n
  hist(z, main=paste("n =", n), freq=FALSE, ylim=c(0, 1/2))
  curve(dnorm(x), add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a great answer already. If you want to complete your own proof, too, you can argue as follows:

Since $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^i$ converges for all $i>1$ and diverges for $i = 1$ ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))), we may write

\begin{align}S(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{3}{k^2} + \frac{4}{k^3} - \frac{3}{k^4} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} + O(1).
\end{align}

By the same argument,

$$
B^2_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} + O(1).
$$

Consequently, $S(n) / B_n^2 = O(1)$ and, thus,

$$
S(n)/B_n^3 = O(1)(B_n^2)^{-1/2} \to 0,
$$

which is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 3):

First your random variables are not identically distributed if the distributions depend on $k$ ;)

Also I wouldn't use your $B_n$ notation as:

- capital letters are usually reserved for random variables.
- it's just the sum of the variances so I would use a notation involving a $\sigma$ symbol to make this obvious.

Then regarding the question I don't know if this is an exercise or research and what tools you're allowed to use. If you're not trying to re-prove known theorems, I'd just say it's a central limit theorem for independent non-identically distributed but uniformly bounded RV and call it a day. I don't have a good source at hand but it shouldn't be too hard to find one, for example look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29508/is-there-a-central-limit-theorem-for-bounded-non-identically-distributed-random.

Edit : My bad, of course the uniformly bounded condition is not enough, you also need $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2 \to \infty$$