# How to show $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \log n}{\sqrt{\log n}} \to_{D} N(0,1)$ for random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ independent?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

I currently have that for  $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $\frac{1}{i}$ random variables,

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\frac{1}{i})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i^2})}} \to_{D} N(0,1)
$$

This fact I established by Lyapunov's.

How can I show that if $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i=\log n+O(1)\qquad \ \text{and} \ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i^2}=O(1)$,

Then:

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \log n}{\sqrt{\log n}} \to_{D} N(0,1)
$$

?

Comment: Use the result at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203894.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sum from 1 to $n$ $1/i = \log n +O(1)$, you can substitute $\log n$ for the sum $1/i$ in the numerator of your result. Furthermore, since sum $1/i^2 = O(1)$ and sum $(1/i -1/i^2)=\log n+O(1)$, $\log n$ can be used to replace the quantity under the square root sign in the denominator.